# select and option tags in Angular reactive forms

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

i'm tryng to create a select with one option for every element in my classes array.

This is my .ts file

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-deck',
  templateUrl: './create-deck.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-deck.component.scss']
})
export class CreateDeckComponent implements OnInit {

  classes: ['Priest', 'Mage', 'Shaman', 'Rogue', 'Warrior', 'Warlock', 'Druid', 'Paladin']
  createDeckForm: FormGroup;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.createDeckForm = new FormGroup({
      'deckName': new FormControl('Meme Deck'),
      'chooseClass': new FormControl('class')
    });
  }
  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.createDeckForm);
    this.createDeckForm.reset();
```

is this the right way to loop over the array element?

And this is the .html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <form [formGroup]="createDeckForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <label for="deckName">Deck Name</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="deckName"
        formControlName="deckName"
        class="form-control"
      />

      <label for="chooseClass">Deck class</label>
      <select id="chooseClass" name="chooseClass">
        <option
            *ngFor="let class of classes"
            [value]="class">
            {{class}}
      </option>
      </select>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: What errors are you getting? Just by glancing at the code you don't have a formControlName attribute on your select element and you're also supplying a value to the ```chooseClass``` formControl that doesn't exist in your array. But your use of the *ngFor directive is correct.

Comment: @nullptr.t The problem is that he is using : like he declare type! He have to change to classes:[] = [.....]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you decalre type instead of assign value to your array.

Change this

```
classes: ['Priest', 'Mage', 'Shaman', 'Rogue', 'Warrior', 'Warlock', 'Druid', 'Paladin']
```

To this

```
classes= ['Priest', 'Mage', 'Shaman', 'Rogue', 'Warrior', 'Warlock', 'Druid', 'Paladin']
```

Or this

```
classes:[] = ['Priest', 'Mage', 'Shaman', 'Rogue', 'Warrior', 'Warlock', 'Druid', 'Paladin']
```

A working [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wyz1bs)